# JQuery form wizard and historyEnabled doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, formwizard

I'm trying Jquery form wizard http://plugins.jquery.com/project/formwizard

And it seems to work until I use historyEnabled: true. Back button stops working (I see in that case history.back() is called, but actually it shows the same step all the time). So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the [history plugin](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html) in your page? It looks like the form wizard uses it to handle the back button support.

Comment: Yes it is included but for some reason it doesn't work properly.